# Plotting data over time, per day (1 graph per day)

Tags: r

I need to plot something called "Posture vs Time" per day.
Basically, I need my Posture on the Y axes, Time on the X axes, and I need 1 graph per day (Maybe have the day included in the title of the graph) A scatter plot should do fine. (So I need to separate the data first per day as well I presume).

Here is an example of my data:

```
head(graph_pre,30)
         Date                Time Axis1 Axis2 Axis3     VM Posture Counter
1  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:00    89    41    39 105.47       2       0
2  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:01    88   135   117 199.14       3       1
3  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:02     0    61     8  61.52       2       1
4  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:03     0    25     0  25.00       1       1
5  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:04     0     0     0   0.00       1       0
6  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:05     0     0     0   0.00       1       0
7  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:06     0    24    35  42.44       3       1
8  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:07     0    28     0  28.00       4       1
9  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:08     4    96    20  98.14       4       0
10 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:09     0    11     0  11.00       4       0
11 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:10     3    91    22  93.67       4       0
12 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:11     9    44     2  44.96       4       0
13 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:12     5     8    16  18.57       4       0
14 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:13     0     8    21  22.47       4       0
15 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:14     1    29    48  56.09       3       1
16 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:15     0     1     3   3.16       4       1
17 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:16     0    17    35  38.91       3       1
18 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:17     0     0     0   0.00       4       1
19 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:18     0     0     5   5.00       4       0
20 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:19     0     0    29  29.00       3       1
21 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:20     0    15    32  35.34       3       0
22 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:21     0     0     0   0.00       4       1
23 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:22     0     0     0   0.00       4       0
24 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:23     0     0     0   0.00       4       0
25 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:24     0     0     0   0.00       4       0
26 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:25     0    28     4  28.28       4       0
27 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:26    13    47    26  55.26       3       1
28 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:27    11    28    68  74.36       3       0
29 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:28     3    48     5  48.35       4       1
30 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:29     0     0     0   0.00       4       0
> dput(head(graph_pre,30))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065), class = "Date"), 
    Time = structure(c(1647265860, 1647265861, 1647265862, 1647265863, 
    1647265864, 1647265865, 1647265866, 1647265867, 1647265868, 
    1647265869, 1647265870, 1647265871, 1647265872, 1647265873, 
    1647265874, 1647265875, 1647265876, 1647265877, 1647265878, 
    1647265879, 1647265880, 1647265881, 1647265882, 1647265883, 
    1647265884, 1647265885, 1647265886, 1647265887, 1647265888, 
    1647265889), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Axis1 = c(89, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 9, 5, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 11, 3, 0), Axis2 = c(41, 
    135, 61, 25, 0, 0, 24, 28, 96, 11, 91, 44, 8, 8, 29, 1, 17, 
    0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 47, 28, 48, 0), Axis3 = c(39, 
    117, 8, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 20, 0, 22, 2, 16, 21, 48, 3, 35, 
    0, 5, 29, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 26, 68, 5, 0), VM = c(105.47, 
    199.14, 61.52, 25, 0, 0, 42.44, 28, 98.14, 11, 93.67, 44.96, 
    18.57, 22.47, 56.09, 3.16, 38.91, 0, 5, 29, 35.34, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 28.28, 55.26, 74.36, 48.35, 0), Posture = c(2, 3, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4), Counter = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

EDIT:

```
graph_pre <-  mutate(graph_pre, day = lubridate::day(Date)) 

ggplot(graph_pre, aes(x = Time, y = Posture))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

[image]

This is the desired output for 1 day (roughly done on excel) Except I'd like to have the time stamp at the bottom (8am-5pm):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data <-  mutate(data, day = lubridate::day(Date)) 

ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = Posture))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, very close however. It is currently giving me the 4 graphs, but the x axis shows date AND Time, which is inaccurate, all plots will be from 8am-5pm, can we force the scaling on the X axes to only show times between 8-5?

Comment: I've added the code you suggested and it's output to the question

Comment: Just to clarify, I need all 4 graphs to have it's X limits be the first and last data point (8am and 5pm) so that it is easier to visualize

Comment: I think you need to add `facet_wrap(~day, scales = "free_x)`

Comment: How can I add a Legend saying 4=Standing, 3=Stepping, 2=Cycling, 1=Sitting